# Groups which are not Lie groups

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, lie-groups

> **Question:** What are examples of set-theoretic groups which do not admit any Lie group structure?

Note that this is different from asking for "[a topological group which is not a Lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1589202)", since here we would need to show that it is not a Lie group for *any* topology.

(**Definition:** I am assuming a Lie group is a second-countable Hausdorff locally-Euclidean space with a smooth structure for which the product and inversion maps are smooth.)

Note that any group with at most countably many elements can be given the structure of a $0$-dimensional Lie group with the discrete topology. Examples would thus have to be uncountable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groups that are not Lie Groups](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1323969/groups-that-are-not-lie-groups)

Comment: The edited version seems not to be a duplicate now. [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/250292/given-a-group-g-how-many-topological-lie-group-structures-does-g-have) is related.

Comment: Kind of a boring example, but according to the convention that manifolds are second countable, locally Euclidean, Hausdorff spaces, it follows that every manifold has cardinality at most that of the real line. So, taking any group with more than continuum-many elements gives an example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take an uncountable direct sum of, say, finite cyclic groups.

Comment: Why can't this be given the structure of a Lie group?

Comment: @NajibIdrissi: Because of the known structure of abelian Lie groups. The connected component of the identify is a product of a compact torus and $R^n$, hence, it cannot be torsion.